# matplotlib stepfilled hist in y-log scale don't show correctly

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I have a problem displaying histograms in matplotlib when both options histtype='stepfilled' and log=True are used. I had this problem in matplotlib version 1.1.0 and found that this is still present in version 1.2.0.

Unfortunately I don't have the rights to post images, but you can check out this behaviour with this simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 200, 25
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, histtype='bar',log=True)
plt.savefig("test1.png")
plt.clf()
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, histtype='stepfilled',log=True)
plt.savefig("test2.png")
```

The first figure shows correctly, whereas in the second case, with the option histtype='stepfilled' instead of 'bar', no.
Somebody has any clue?

Answer (score 1):

It's an open bug in matplotlib. Maybe you can simulate the `stepfilled` manipulating the style of the bars in the first graphic.

The issue on github:

- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/196

Comment: For information, bug has been corrected in January 2013, and a working fix is available in the issue you link.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, histtype='stepfilled')
plt.semilogy()
```

you get the expected result, with the caveat that it looks weird for bins with zero values.