# matplotlib stepfilled histogram breaks at the value 10^-1 on xubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Why is it that when the code is run through python the graph seems to break down at 10^-1 on the y-axis?(Code below)

```
from pylab import *

bins = [+0.000e+00,+1.000e+00,+2.000e+00,+3.000e+00,+4.000e+00,+5.000e+00]
wght = [[+3.000e-02,+7.0e-02,+3.0e-01,+5.0e-01,+8.0e-01]]

hist([ bins[:-1] for i in range(len(wght)) ], bins=bins, weights=wght,histtype="stepfilled", log=True )

ylim(bottom=0.01); ylim(top=1.0)

savefig("./output.pdf")
```

What it should look like:
[image: Correct image stepping past 10**-1]

What it actually looks like:

[image: Broken output]

I am currently running python 2.7 on Xubuntu 14.04, and this error happens on many histograms. For some reason when opened and run through Python(x,y) on Windows we get the first histogram(What it should look like) but when I move onto python on Xubuntu all the graphs I try to run similar to this one all have issues at the 10^-1 on the y-axis.(What it actually looks like) What can I do with this code to make sure it outputs the first gyazo picture on any python version I want to run?

Comment: The output was as excepted with python 2.7 and matplotlib 1.4.2, but not with python 2.7 and matplotlib 1.3.1 (xubuntu 14.04 / trusty). What was the version of the matplotlib on Windows?

Comment: This has been an issue before, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/196

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583443/matplotlib-stepfilled-hist-in-y-log-scale-dont-show-correctly

Comment: I believe the matplotlib version is 1.4.3.

Comment: It can be verified with `python -c 'import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)'`

Comment: 1.4.3 on Windows, 1.3.1 on xubuntu, ah i see. I downloaded and installed matplotlib 1.5.1 but it still says I have the 1.3.1 version after I run the line above again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is present in older versions, installing a new version is recommended.

The output was as excepted with python 2.7 and matplotlib 1.4.2 (debian / jessie), but not with python 2.7 and matplotlib 1.3.1 (xubuntu 14.04 / trusty).

The version of the matplotlib can be checked with

```
python -c 'import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)'
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there are any known workarounds for when an older version is in use?